# Best linear interpolation with expensive-to-compute function

Tags: algorithms, regression, linear-regression

I have a function $f(n)$ which is hard to evaluate, but which can be well-approximated as $an+b$ for unknown real constants $a,b.$ Say the time needed to evaluate $f(n)$ is $b(n)$ where $b$ is sufficiently nice. (In the example immediately at hand, $b(n)=n^2,$ and the errors $|an+b-f(n)|$ seem quite small, logarithmic or possibly even bounded; make reasonable assumptions as needed.)

I would like to spend a certain amount of time to estimate $a$ (or $a,b$) as precisely as possible. I could compute $a(1),a(2),\ldots,a(n)$ for some $n$ (in my example, costing about $n^3/3$), but the interior points won't end up mattering much. At the other extreme, I could evaluate $f(1)$ and $f(m)$ with $m$ as large as I can afford (in my example, $kn^{1.5}$ with $k\approx0.58$) and fit a line; this gives maximal separation but is subject to errors. A similar approach would be to evaluate a few points near 1 and a few points as high as possible.

I understand that this question is under-specified: I don't know the distribution of the error term, I haven't specified which metric (I was using $L^2$ in my example, but it doesn't need to be that), etc. I'm hoping that there is a good method which will suggest natural parameters. Often good answers require tweaking the question a bit. :)

Comment: The structure of the error function is important, this will tell you how far apart you can take the points to avoid losing significant digits. Also you want to use extrapolation methods to get to accurate results and that requires making some assumptions about the error term.

Comment: @CountIblis Ah -- this makes me realize I had left out the important detail that $f:\mathbb{Z}^+\to\mathbb{Z}^+$ and I can compute the terms exactly. But it's quite costly to evaluate large terms: $f(10^5)$ might take days. But since the function seems extraordinarily well-behaved I thought there was hope to find a good linear estimate. The function is not monotone but it's rare that $|f(n+1)-f(n)|>10$, say.